# How do i update a usercontrol which is in master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

i want to update a user control from content page, and user control is in master page.

anybody have any idea about it ?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: I have a control where i'm showing Cart item count,
and i want that whenever i add any item, cart will update.

Comment: this is what you want to do... but i asked what did you try before asking this question

Comment: Please provide some more details. What you have already tried? Where are you stuck? See also: [How to ask a question?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is in your user control Expose the label (make it public).

```
public class MyUCtrl : UserControl{
    public Label MyLabel{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then in the Master Page do something similar:

```
 public MyUCtrl Counter{ get; set; }
 ...
```

Then in the content page:

```
((MyMasterPage)this.Master).Counter.MyLabel.Text = "hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add property in your `UserControl` like this:

```
public int ItemCount{ get;set; }
public string CountText
{
   get{ return labelId.Text; }
   set{ labelId.Text = "Item in shopcart: "+ ItemCount; }
}
```

then in your `aspx` make on add item to cart (`button click` or something whatever you want)

```
YouUserControlId.ItemCount++;
```